# Java logging level is ignored in properties file

Tags: java, logging

I have the following `logging.properties` file for java logging, which is a slightly modified version of the default `logging.properties` file that comes with the JDK:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

# Default global logging level.
# This specifies which kinds of events are logged across
# all loggers.  For any given facility this global level
# can be overriden by a facility specific level
# Note that the ConsoleHandler also has a separate level
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.
.level = INFO

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=FINEST
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = CONFIG
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

The level settings for `FileHandler` and `ConsoleHandler` are ignored. They only work if I set global `.level = FINEST`. It seems, that `.level` acts as global limit to what can be logged. From the description, however, I would have expected that the settings in `FileHandler` and `ConsoleHandler`
override the global setting.

Do I need additional settings to configure?

PS: Java version is 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Logging Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) will give you a breakdown of how the logging framework is setup.

The line `.level = FINEST` determines the [level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setLevel-java.util.logging.Level-) of the root logger. Meaning that if you have `log` calls in your code they will generate log records which will be published to the attached handers and possibly to parent handlers.

The `java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=FINEST` line determines the lowest [level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Handler.html#setLevel-java.util.logging.Level-) that will be published to the output file.  For instance, `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = CONFIG` will only publish records CONFIG and higher to the console.